# Sending specific Json api data to view Laravel 8

Tags: php

Hi Im using Laravel 8 And Im new here and struggling so much .

On my Controller I have this .

```
        $coinsphapi = json_decode(Http::get('https://quote.coins.ph/v1/markets'));
```

I only want to get The bid of BTC-ETH But I dont know how to show the number data of bid .

I tried

```
@foreach ($coinsphapi->markets  as $item)
{{$item->bid}}
```

But it shows the entire symbol on the api

Comment: `@foreach ($coinsphapi->markets as $key => $item)`   `$key` is the number data of bid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they point out in their [API Documentation](https://docs.coins.asia/docs/market-rates), you can call the market value for a specific currency like BTC-ETH

```
$coinsphapi = json_decode(Http::get('https://quote.coins.ph/v1/markets/BTC-ETH'));
```

Then echo the bid directly without looping

```
{{$coinsphapi->market->bid}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that solved my problem